# spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled for Spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am  using the 'preview' Google DataProc Image 1.1 with Spark 2.0.0. To complete one of my operations I have to complete a cartesian product. Since version 2.0.0 there has been a spark configuration parameter created (spark.sql.cross Join.enabled) that prohibits cartesian products and an  Exception is thrown. How can I set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true, preferably by using an initialization action?
`spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For changing default values of configuration settings in Dataproc, you don't even need an init action, you can use the [--properties flag](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/concepts/cluster-properties) when creating your cluster from the command-line:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties spark:spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true my-cluster ...
```

Answer (score 29):

**Spark >= 3.0**

`spark.sql.crossJoin.enable` is true by default ([SPARK-28621](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28621)).

**Spark >= 2.1**

You can use `crossJoin`:

```scala
df1.crossJoin(df2)
```

It makes your intention explicit and keeps more conservative configuration in place to protect you from unintended cross joins.

**Spark 2.0**

SQL properties can be set dynamically on runtime with `RuntimeConfig.set` method so you should be able to call

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)
```

whenever you want to explicitly allow Cartesian product.

Comment: It looks like `crossJoin()` isn't available on `DataFrame`/`Dataset` prior to spark 2.1.

Comment: @RickHaffey for versions prior to Spark 2.1, use the `dataset.join(rightDataset)` API with the `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)` configuration option. This style also works with Spark 2.1, but the .crossJoin API is ideal as it's more explicit.

Comment: if you are working in iPython `true` should be `True`

Answer (score 1):

The TPCDS query set benchmarks have queries that contain `CROSS JOINS` and unless you explicitly write `CROSS JOIN` or dynamically set Spark's default property to true `Spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)` you will run into an exception error.

The error appears on TPCDS queries 28,61, 88, and 90 becuase the original query syntax from Transaction Processing Committee (TPC) contains commas and Spark's default join operation is an inner join. My team has also decided to use `CROSS JOIN` in lieu of changing Spark's default properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", True)
```

Otherwise it'll give

> NameError: name 'true' is not defined