# How to use Column.isin with array column in join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
case class Foo1(codes:Seq[String], name:String)
case class Foo2(code:String, description:String)

val ds1 = Seq(
  Foo1(Seq("A"),           "foo1"),
  Foo1(Seq("A", "B"),      "foo2"),
  Foo1(Seq("B", "C", "D"), "foo3"),
  Foo1(Seq("C"),           "foo4"),
  Foo1(Seq("C", "D"),      "foo5")
).toDS

val ds2 = Seq(
  Foo2("A", "product A"),
  Foo2("B", "product B"),
  Foo2("C", "product C"),
  Foo2("D", "product D"),
  Foo2("E", "product E")
).toDS

val j = ds1.join(ds2, ds2("code") isin (ds1("codes")))
```

Hopefully this Scala code fragment makes it clear what I'm trying to accomplish, our data is structured so that one data set has a column which contains an array of values, and I wish to join the values within that collection to another data set.  So for example `Seq("A", "B")` in `ds1` would join with `"A"` and `"B"` in `ds2`.

The "isin" operator on Column seems to be exactly what I want, and this builds and runs, but when I run it I get the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`code` IN (`codes`))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type;;

Reading further I see that `isin()` wants to take a varargs ("splatted args") and seems more suitable for a `filter()`. So my question is, is this the intended use of this operator, or is there some other way to perform this type of join?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use `array_contains`:

```
ds1.crossJoin(ds2).where("array_contains(codes, code)").show

+---------+----+----+-----------+
|    codes|name|code|description|
+---------+----+----+-----------+
|      [A]|foo1|   A|  product A|
|   [A, B]|foo2|   A|  product A|
|   [A, B]|foo2|   B|  product B|
|[B, C, D]|foo3|   B|  product B|
|[B, C, D]|foo3|   C|  product C|
|[B, C, D]|foo3|   D|  product D|
|      [C]|foo4|   C|  product C|
|   [C, D]|foo5|   C|  product C|
|   [C, D]|foo5|   D|  product D|
+---------+----+----+-----------+
```

If you use Spark 1.x or 2.0 replace `crossJoin` with standard join, and [enable cross joins in configuration, if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38999140/9613318).

It might by possible to avoid Cartesian product with `explode`:

```
ds1.withColumn("code", explode($"codes")).join(ds2, Seq("code")).show
+----+---------+----+-----------+                                               
|code|    codes|name|description|
+----+---------+----+-----------+
|   B|   [A, B]|foo2|  product B|
|   B|[B, C, D]|foo3|  product B|
|   D|[B, C, D]|foo3|  product D|
|   D|   [C, D]|foo5|  product D|
|   C|[B, C, D]|foo3|  product C|
|   C|      [C]|foo4|  product C|
|   C|   [C, D]|foo5|  product C|
|   A|      [A]|foo1|  product A|
|   A|   [A, B]|foo2|  product A|
+----+---------+----+-----------+
```