# Spark: How to join two `Dataset`s A and B with the condition that an ID array column of A does NOT contain the ID column of B?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset

### My question is not a duplicate of [[Joining Spark Dataframes with "isin" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487666/joining-spark-dataframes-with-isin-operator]). My question is about "not in", not "is in". It is DIFFERENT!

I have two `Dataset`s:

- `userProfileDataset`: `Dataset[UserProfile]`
- `jobModelsDataset`:  `Dataset[JobModel]`

Case clss `UserProfile` is defined as

```
case class UserProfile(userId: Int, visitedJobIds: Array[Int])
```

and case class `JobModel` is defined as

```
case class JobModel(JobId: Int, Model: Map[String, Double])
```

I have also made two objects (`UserProfileFieldNames` and `JobModelFieldNames`) that contains the field names of these two case classes.

**My objective is, for each user in `userProfileDataset`, find the `JobModel.JobId`s that are NOT contained in `UserProfile.visitedJobIds`**.
**How to do this?**

I've thought about using a `crossJoin` and then `filter`. It may work. Is there more direct or efficient ways?

---

I have tried the following approaches, but none of them worked:

```
val result = userProfileDataset.joinWith(jobModelsDataset,
      !userProfileDataset.col(UserProfileFieldNames.visitedJobIds).contains(jobModelsDataset.col(JobModelFieldNames.jobId)),
      "left_outer"
    )
```

It leads to:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve 'contains(`_1`.`visitedJobIds`, CAST(`_2`.`JobId` AS
>   STRING))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type,
>   however, '`_1`.`visitedJobIds`' is of array type.;;

Could it be because the `contains` method can be only used for testing whether one string contains another string?

The following condition also didn't work:

```
!jobModelsDataset.col(JobModelFieldNames.jobId)
  .isin(userProfileDataset.col(UserProfileFieldNames.visitedJobIds))
```

It leads to:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve '(`_2`.`JobId` IN (`_1`.`visitedJobIds`))' due to data
>   type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: IntegerType !=
>   ArrayType(IntegerType,false);; 'Join LeftOuter, NOT _2#74.JobId IN
>   (_1#73.visitedJobIds)

Comment: It sounds like the number of JobIds are quite low. If that is the case, collecting all unique JobIds and then comparing would be a possible approach.

Comment: @Shaido Do you mean broadcast the collected JobIds and then compare with the `visitedJobIds` column?
 How to compare an Array[Int] with a column then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of unique job ids are not too many, then you can collect and broadcast those as follows

```
val jobIds = jobModelsDataset.map(_.JobId).distinct.collect().toSeq
val broadcastedJobIds = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(jobIds)
```

To compare this broadcasted sequence with the `visitedJobIds` column you can create an `UDF`

```
val notVisited = udf((visitedJobs: Seq[Int]) => { 
  broadcastedJobIds.value.filterNot(visitedJobs.toSet)
})

val df = userProfileDataset.withColumn("jobsToDo", notVisited($"visitedJobIds"))
```

Testing with `jobIds = 1,2,3,4,5` and an example dataframe

```
+------+---------------+
|userId|  visitedJobIds|
+------+---------------+
|     1|      [1, 2, 3]|
|     2|      [3, 4, 5]|
|     3|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+------+---------------+
```

will give a final dataframe as

```
+------+---------------+--------+
|userId|  visitedJobIds|jobsToDo|
+------+---------------+--------+
|     1|      [1, 2, 3]|  [4, 5]|
|     2|      [3, 4, 5]|  [1, 2]|
|     3|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|      []|
+------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `explode` the *array* column of `userProfileDataset` and `cast` it to `IntegerType` to `join` with `jobModelsDataset`'s `JobId` *column* which is already an *IntegerType*. Then finally use `collect_list` *inbuilt function* to get the final result.

*Exploding* and *casting* would be as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val temp = userProfileDataset.withColumn("visitedJobIds", explode(col("visitedJobIds")))
    .withColumn("visitedJobIds", col("visitedJobIds").cast(IntegerType))
```

*joining* and *collecting* would be as below

```
temp.join(jobModelsDataset, temp("visitedJobIds") === jobModelsDataset("JobId"), "left")
      .groupBy("userId")
      .agg(collect_list("visitedJobIds").as("visitedJobIds"), collect_list("JobId").as("ModelJobIds"))
    .show(false)
```

You should get what you are looking for

**Updated**

If you are looking for `JobIds` that each `userId` is not associated with then you can do as below.

```
val list = jobModelsDataset.select(collect_list("JobId")).rdd.first()(0).asInstanceOf[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]
def notContained = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => list.filter(x => !(array.contains(x))))
temp.join(jobModelsDataset, temp("visitedJobIds") === jobModelsDataset("JobId"), "left")
      .groupBy("userId")
      .agg(collect_list("visitedJobIds").as("visitedJobIds"), collect_list("JobId").as("ModelJobIds"))
      .withColumn("ModelJobIds", notContained(col("ModelJobIds")))
    .show(false)
```

You can improve the answer by `broadcasting`.

Comment: I want to find the jobs in `jobModelsDataset` that are NOT visited by each user according to the `visitedJobIds` column of `userProfileDataset`. So I guess I should change `===` in your codes to `=!=`. However that probably can not achieve the original objective.

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领, I have updated my answer :) please test it :)

Comment: What is the difference it makes here to broadcast `list` and not broadcast it? It seems in your codes `list` is collected by the Driver?

Comment: yes list should be collected to get one list. broadcasting will help to use memory efficiently as only the requested data from broadcasted variable will be distributed to executors and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I had another approach which uses `crossJoin` and then `filter`:

```
val result = userProfileDataset
  .crossJoin(jobModelsDataset) // 27353040 rows
  .filter(row => !row(2).asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]].contains(row.getInt(3))) //27352633 rows
```

If I use @Shaido's approach then `explode`, I should be able to obtain the same result of this approach. However this approach is very expensive even with a `filter` in my case (I have compared the time elapsed). The `explain` method can also print out the Physical Plan.

So I will not use the crossJoin approach. I just want to post and keep it here.