# sparklyr - Including null values in an Apache Spark Join

Tags: r, apache-spark, join, dplyr, sparklyr

The question [Including null values in an Apache Spark Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728762/including-null-values-in-an-apache-spark-join) has answers for Scala, PySpark and SparkR, but not for sparklyr. I've been unable to figure out how to have `inner_join` in sparklyr treat null values in a join column as equal. Does anyone know how this can be done in sparklyr?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke an implicit cross join:

```
#' Return a Cartesian product of Spark tables
#'
#' @param df1 tbl_spark
#' @param df2 tbl_spark
#' @param explicit logical If TRUE use crossJoin otherwise 
#'   join without expression
#' @param suffix character suffixes to be used on duplicate names
cross_join <- function(df1, df2, 
    explicit = FALSE, suffix = c("_x", "_y")) {

  common_cols <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))

  if(length(common_cols) > 0) {
    df1 <- df1 %>% rename_at(common_cols, funs(paste0(., suffix[1])))
    df2 <- df2 %>% rename_at(common_cols, funs(paste0(., suffix[2])))
  }

  sparklyr::invoke(
    spark_dataframe(df1), 
    if(explicit) "crossJoin" else "join", 
    spark_dataframe(df2)) %>% sdf_register()
}
```

and filter the result with `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

```
# Enable Cross joins
sc %>% 
  spark_session() %>% 
  sparklyr::invoke("conf") %>%
  sparklyr::invoke("set", "spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")

df1 <- copy_to(sc, tibble(id1 = c(NA, "foo", "bar"), val = 1:3))
df2 <- copy_to(sc, tibble(id2 = c(NA, "foo", "baz"), val = 4:6))

df1 %>%
  cross_join(df2) %>% 
  filter(id1 %IS NOT DISTINCT FROM% id2)
```

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
  id1   val_x id2   val_y
* <chr> <int> <chr> <int>
1 NA        1 NA        4
2 foo       2 foo       5
```

The [optimized execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614889/6910411):

```
<jobj[62]>
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Join
  Join Inner, (id1#10 <=> id2#76)
:- Project [id1#10, val#11 AS val_x#129]
:  +- InMemoryRelation [id1#10, val#11], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
:        +- Scan ExistingRDD[id1#10,val#11]
+- Project [id2#76, val#77 AS val_y#132]
   +- InMemoryRelation [id2#76, val#77], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- Scan ExistingRDD[id2#76,val#77]
```

`<=>` operator should work the same way:

```
df1 %>%
  cross_join(df2) %>% 
  filter(id1 %<=>% id2)
```

Please note that:

- Implicit cross join will fail, if it is not followed by selection which promotes the result to hash join / sort merge join, or cross join [is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38999140/6910411).
- Explicit cross join shouldn't be used in this case, as it will take precedence over subsequent selections.
- It is possible to use `dplyr` style cross join:

  ```
  mutate(df1, `_const` = TRUE) %>%  
    inner_join(mutate(df2, `_const` = TRUE), by = c("_const")) %>% 
    select(-`_const`) %>% 
    filter(id1 %IS NOT DISTINCT FROM% id2)
  ```

  but I'd advise against that, as it is less robust (depending on the context optimizer might be unable to recognize that `_const` is constant).

Answer (score 0):

Since sparklyr uses dplyr as the front-end of choice, I would expect using the `na_matches = "na"` argument in `dplyr::inner_join()` would to be the "canonical" way of doing it:

```r
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect("local")
mtcars_spark <- sparklyr::sdf_copy_to(sc, datasets::mtcars)
mtcars_spark_with_nulls <- dplyr::mutate(mtcars_spark, naCol = as.character(NA))

dplyr::inner_join(
  mtcars_spark_with_nulls,
  mtcars_spark_with_nulls,
  na_matches = "na"
)
```

As of today, the code above has a small caveat: in the current CRAN version of dbplyr there is still [this bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/787). Since this is already fixed and merged in GitHub, you can make the code above runnable by installing the current GitHub version:

```
remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dbplyr")
```

If you would like more efficiency, perhaps using Spark's built-in `<=>` operator would be more efficient than the [generic implementation within dbplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/2b54f9f0d6f82ecd7211ef0652e4b354d502984d/R/db-sql.R#L88). You could introduce a method such as the following for `spark_connection` objects:

```r
sql_expr_matches.spark_connection <- function(con, x, y) {
  dbplyr::build_sql(x, " <=> ", y, con = con)
}
```