# Avoid Cartesian Join for the spark SQL query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the processRate from the total count of two temp tables but I'm getting the error "Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans" where I am not even performing joins. I am sure this error can be resolved by restructuring the query in correct format and I need your help on it. Below is the query,

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW final_processRate AS
SELECT
      ((a.total - b.total)/a.total))* 100 AS processRate
FROM
    (select count (*) as total from sales) a,
    (select count (*) as total from sales where status = 'PENDING') b
""")
```

I'm getting this error while trying to view the data using,

```
spark.sql("select * from processRate limit 10").show(false)
```

Can you please help on formatting the above query to resolve this issue and view the data of `final_processRate`?

Comment: *"where I am not even performing joins"* - why do you think this is **not** a join? I mean, you have `FROM a,b` - what else if not a join is this?

Comment: also, you can enable cross join for Spark, though a cartesian product is supposed to be slow in general:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000050/4744359 - for Spark 3 it would be enabled by default, so you're using an older version of Spark anyways. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need subquery for this. Just use a conditional aggregation:

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW final_processRate AS
SELECT
    ((count(*) - count(case when status='PENDING' then 1 end)) / count(*)) * 100 AS processRate
FROM sales
""")
```

Then you can query the temp view using:

```
spark.sql("select * from final_processRate")
```

which should give you a single number/percentage calculated above.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked!! Can you please explain the difference between the two queries ? It will be really helpful for me to understand the logic on deeper level.

Comment: Your query involves an implicit cross join between a and b because you have two tables in `from`, which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select avg(case when status = 'PENDING' then 0.0 else 1 end)
from sales;
```

This returns the proportion of rows that are not pending.